# Relation of v at apogee and perigee

Tags: rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, rotational-kinematics

I seem to be confusing something about angular momentum and its relation to linear momentum.

$L = I\omega$

so for a constant I, L is proportional to ω.

$$\frac{L_1}{L_2} =  \frac{ω_1}{ω_2} $$

since $ω = \frac{v}{r}$, given a closed system where L is also constant,

$$\frac{L_1}{L_2} =  \frac{v_1r_2}{v_2r_1} = 1$$

$$\frac{v_1}{v_2} = \frac{r_1}{r_2}$$

$v$ is proportional to $r$.

but $L = pr = mvr$,

so $\frac{L_1}{L_2} = mv_1r_1 = mv_2r_2 = 1$

cancelling $m$,

we get

$$\frac{v_1}{v_2} = \frac{r_2}{r_1}$$

so $v$ is inversely proportional to $r$.

Does anyone know where my logic breaks down?

PS, this came from a mastering physics question about elliptical orbits I got wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It breaks down in the second line. $I$ is not constant when you change $r$, but instead is proportional to $r^2$. Your argument $v$ is inversely proportional to $r$ is fine, and indeed that is the right result.